# What is meaning of 4 letter abbreviations in Roman names like Titus Flavius T. f. T. n. Sabinus?

Tags: ancient-rome, everyday-life, names

I am reading about [Titus Flavius Sabinus (consul AD 47)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titus_Flavius_Sabinus_(consul_AD_47)) and cannot find meaning of *T. f. T. n.* in his full name as written in Wikipedia, "Titus Flavius T. f. T. n. Sabinus."

All I have found is a [list of roman consuls and military tribunes](https://books.google.sk/books?id=-0IH68Du9jcC&pg=PT251&lpg=PT251&dq=t.f.t.n.+history&source=bl&ots=BNjWLXE8IV&sig=ACfU3U2RXyOg7JGm_Zsn2XyC9vCo476y2Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvn-Gn1pPjAhXJNcAKHV6VBYkQ6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=t.f.t.n.&f=false) where similar abbreviations are used with various letters.

Searching for *TFTN* or *T. f. T. n.* returns modern abbreviations like "Thanks For The Numbers," "The Free Times Newspaper," nothing relevant.

Reading the [wiki page history](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Titus_Flavius_Sabinus_(consul_AD_47)&diff=534662796&oldid=534461285) I see no indication why this abbreviation was inserted.

My guess would be *T. f. T. n.* is abbreviation of province or military regiment?

Comment: It's a form of [filiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_naming_conventions#Filiation), I'll let some smarter folk give the full answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It stands for *"Titi filius Titi nepos"*, meaning "son of Titus and grandson of Titus" (*filius* and *nepos* mean son and grandson, respectively).

This is because the consul [Titus Flavius Sabinus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titus_Flavius_Sabinus_(consul_AD_47)) was the son of the (non-consul) [Titus Flavius Sabinus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titus_Flavius_Sabinus_(father_of_Vespasian)), who was in turn the son of [Titus Flavius Petro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titus_Flavius_Petro). So as @SteveBird observed, the abbreivations are "filiation", i.e. the part of the name describing paternity.

Note that we can determine both T.'s stand for Titus because there's a set formula for how these names are abbreviated. In Roman names, the first part, known as [*praenomen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praenomen) (in examples above, "Titus") are the personal names. However, there were only ever about three dozens of these, and only ten or so were common in the historical record.

As a result, there are standardised abbreviations:

- Aulus = A.
- Gaius = C.
- Gnaeus = Cn.
- Decimus = D.
- Lucius = L.
- Marcus = M.
- Publius = P.
- Quintus = Q.
- Titus = T.
- Tiberius = Ti.

---

Roman naming conventions are very annoying.

Comment: [Australia later adopted a similar naming convention for its philosophy professors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gw1Ur62x0Q)

Comment: Just an aside to @Semaphore 's excellent answer, as freedmen generally took their former master's *praenomen* and *nomen*, it helped to distinguish sons from freedmen. So Q. Tullius Cicero **f.** M would be Quintus, Cicero's son, whilst M. Tullius Tiro **l.** M would indicate Tiro, Cicero's *libertus* or freedman.

Comment: @BobJarvis : your link already appears to be dead.

Comment: H = Hexadecimus ("0x" if a eunuch).

Comment: `there were only ever about three dozens of these, and only ten or so were common in the historical record` — and each family was using about 4-5 of them at best.

Comment: @vsz: it works for me. ???

Comment: @Kaz Thank you for the insight, I always though that the eunuchs operating system was much more modern thing!

Comment: @vsz the [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gw1Ur62x0Q) is [only available in the USA](https://polsy.org.uk/stuff/ytrestrict.cgi?ytid=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D8gw1Ur62x0Q)

Comment: This is available in Canada, unlike that youtube link, so it might be available in places other than the United States as well.

https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x6gf7gk  

Advance to the 2:12 mark, although that might violate rules 1, 3, 5, and 7.

Answer (score 7):

> The personal name in the Roman naming system  is composed of several
>   independent elements.
>
> A Roman male name of the late Republic such as
>
> *Q. Numerius Q. f. Vel. Rufus* comprises the following:
>
> 1. the praenomen or the old individual name (siglum Q = Quintus ),
> 2. the gentile or family name (Numerius),
> 3. **the filiation, which gives the praenomen of the father in the genitive   (usually as a siglum) before the abbreviated f(ilius)
>      (Quinti filius 'son of Quintus') and in highly official texts also the
>      praenomen of the grandfather (cf. Fasti consulares, 260 BC: Cn.
>      Cornelius L. f. Cn(aei) n(epos) Scipio Asina),**
> 4. the indication of the tribus in a defined abbreviation (Vel(inā tribū): abl. of quality), and
> 5. the cognomen , which as an individual cognomen was the younger individual name and as a hereditary cognomen served to differentiate
>      the branches (stirpes) of noble families (Gens) (for example, combined
>      in Scipio Asina).    Since use of the cognomen was not a universal
>      custom even in the late Republic (for example, it is missing for the
>      victor over the Cimbri, C. Marius [I 1] and the triumvir M. Antonius
>      [I 9])    and the oldest son usually adopted his father’s praenomen,
>      the system did not always permit identification of a person,
>      especially between generations.
>
> However, it generally fulfilled its function superbly even in a large
>   society.

<sub>–– The above adapted in formatting from: Rix, Helmut (Freiburg), García-Ramón, José Luis (Cologne), Streck, Michael P. (Munich) and Haas, Volkert (Berlin), “Personal names”, in: Brill’s New Pauly, Antiquity volumes edited by: Hubert Cancik and , Helmuth Schneider, English Edition by: Christine F. Salazar, Classical Tradition volumes edited by: Manfred Landfester, English Edition by: Francis G. Gentry.  http://dx.doi.org/10.1163/1574-9347_bnp_e915460</sub>

So we see that Wikipedia is a highly official Roman text and as such uses the filiation of father *and* grandfather of  *Titus Flavius T.f. T.n. Sabinus*, which very creatively were also named [Titus Flavius Sabinus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titus_Flavius_Sabinus_(father_of_Vespasian)) *(Titus Flavius T.f. Sabinus )*, just like [a few others…](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Titus_Flavius_Sabinus_(disambiguation)&redirect=no)